# Angular select option shows blank when assigned from array

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to show my strings array in select dropdown. I tried the normal way :

```
<form [formGroup]="emailForm" #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="sendEmail()" novalidate class="tooltip-center-bottom">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="emailTem" class="form-control" formControlName="emailTem" [(ngModel)]="emailTem">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select Email Template</option>
      <option *ngFor="let obj of emailArray" [ngValue]="obj">{{obj}}</option>    
    </select>
    <div *ngIf="statusForm.get('status').errors?.required && form.submitted" class="invalid-tooltip">Status is required!</div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary status-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The array i have assigned :

```
emailArray: string[] = [
    'Call Not Connected',
    'Refund'
];
```

it was working before normal. But now it's not showing blank

[image: dropdown]

if i try with normal by setting values directly like this : `<option value="New" ng-reflect-value="New">New</option>` it works properly

Even [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-problem?file=src/app/app.component.html) not working

Comment: Why do you use reactive form and template driven form together?
I think you can remove `#form="ngForm"`.
Please check `emailArray` object in the `console.log()` on the `ts`.

Comment: @oz1985oz i usually don't work as frontend developer and new to angular framework but i read it helps to assign values retrived from api and formcontrol help me to set validator for control

Comment: it's [printing](https://prnt.sc/ztahdl) properly. i just printed the with normal stringify

Comment: They both (reactive form and template driven form) are the same. They contain the same information / methods. The main difference is `template driven form` is mostly on HTML and `reactive form` is mostly on `ts`.

Comment: @oz1985oz does it affect my select option because i was using before and it was working great. But when i tried to update the page. It stopped working

Comment: Can you post it on https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Comment: i can do it for you guys

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228826/discussion-between-ashish-and-oz1985oz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="sendEmail()" class="tooltip-center-bottom">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="emailTem" class="form-control" name="email" [(ngModel)]="emailTem">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select Email Template</option>
      <option *ngFor="let obj of emailArray" [value]="obj">{{obj}}</option>    
    </select>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary status-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: <select id="emailTem" class="form-control" formControlName="emailTem" [(ngModel)]="emailTem">
What is the need of using both the formControlName and [(ngModel)]. You are trying to use both the template driven and  reactive form . Please remove [(ngModel)].

Comment: I am not a frontend developer but i assigned values retrieved from api.

Comment: Somehow it worked on stackbliz but not on my computer

Answer (score 1):

Please try with...

**.html file**

```
<form [formGroup]="emailForm" #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="sendEmail()" novalidate class="tooltip-center-bottom">
<div class="form-group">
    <select id="emailTem" class="form-control" formControlName="emailTem" >
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select Email Template</option>
  <option *ngFor="let obj of emailArray" [ngValue]="obj">{{obj}}</option>
</select>
    <!-- <div *ngIf="emailForm.get('email').errors?.required && form.submitted" class="invalid-tooltip">Status is
        required!</div> -->
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary status-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

there is problem with validation So remove or comment that part and it will work fine
[Soluation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-problem-1wd8ao?file=src/app/app.component.html)
hope it will work fine !

Comment: Nope it's not working same output just blank options

Comment: @Ashish Okay give me 2 min

Comment: @Ashish remove all [(ngModel)] inside <form> tag

Comment: Not working please check my stackbliz i added so other can contribute

Comment: @Ashish please check updated answer there is problem with your code

Comment: can you explain more properly what was the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo get('email'):

```
<div *ngIf="emailForm.get('email').errors?.required && form.submitted" class="invalid-tooltip">Status is
            required!</div>
```

Should be get('emailTem'):

```
<div *ngIf="emailForm.get('emailTem').errors?.required && form.submitted" class="invalid-tooltip">Status is
            required!</div>
```

Comment: But it doesn't solve my problem. My main problem was it didn't show my list

Comment: Did you change it as above and it still didn't work? I found it out in your Stackblitz. With the typo there is an error in the console and from then on things break

Answer (score 0):

Try this Angular Reactive form with validation and get value on submit -

**app.component.html -**

```
<form [formGroup]="emailForm" (ngSubmit)="sendEmail()" novalidate class="tooltip-center-bottom">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select id="emailTem" class="form-control" formControlName="emailTem">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select Email Template</option>
      <option *ngFor="let obj of emailArray" [value]="obj">{{obj}}</option>    
    </select>
        <br><br>
        <div *ngIf="formSubmit && emailTem.errors">
            <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="emailTem.errors.required">Status is required!</div>
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary status-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**app.component.ts -**

```
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

export class AppComponent {
    emailForm: FormGroup;
    formSubmit: boolean = false;
    emailArray: string[] = ["Call Not Connected", "Refund"];

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.emailForm = new FormGroup({
          emailTem: new FormControl("", [Validators.required])
        });
    }

    sendEmail() {
        this.formSubmit = true;
        if(this.emailForm.valid){
            console.log(this.emailForm.value.emailTem); // selected value
        }
    }

    get emailTem() {
        return this.emailForm.get("emailTem");
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts -**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Example -**

[image: angular-reactive-form]